# How to toggle Bootstrap popover on dynamically-added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover that is shown and hidden on a click action in some static element:

```
$('.check-out-cell').click(function() { // Close other popovers
    $('.popover').remove();
});

var newPopoverTemplate = '<div class="popover ...</div>';
$('.check-out-cell').popover({
    template: newPopoverTemplate,
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        console.log("asd");
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});

$('.check-out-cell').click(function() {
  var popover = $(this).parent().find('.popover');
  configureSelectize(popover);
  configureDatepickers(popover);

  // Updates the dates in case they were modified
  popover.find('.start-date-input').val($(this).attr("data-start-date"));
  popover.find('.end-date-input').val( ymd(moment($(this).attr("data-end-date")).add(1,'days')));

  popover.find('.input-daterange .date-input').on('changeDate', function() {
  validateReservationDates($(this.form).find('.start-date-input'), $(this.form).find('.end-date-input'));
});

function configureSelectize(context) {
  context.find('.input-tags').selectize({
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      create: function(input) {
          return {
              value: input,
              text: input
          }
      }
  });
}

function configureDatepickers(context) {
  context.find('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      orientation: "top",
      todayBtn: "linked",
      language: $('html').attr('lang')
  }).on('show', function(e) {
    $(".datepicker").css("top", $(e.target).outerHeight() + $(e.target).offset().top);
  });
  $("body").scroll(function() {
    $('.input-daterange').trigger('show');
  });
}
```

This works perfectly when my "check-out-cell"s are not modified. At some point, I remove this and dynamically generate new ones. I can delegate the action of the click() like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.check-out-cell', function() {
    $('.popover').remove();
});

var newPopoverTemplate = '<div class="popover ...</div>';
$('.check-out-cell').popover({
    template: newPopoverTemplate,
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        console.log("asd");
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '.check-out-cell', function() {
  var popover = $(this).parent().find('.popover');
  configureSelectize(popover);
  configureDatepickers(popover);

  // Updates the dates in case they were modified
  popover.find('.start-date-input').val($(this).attr("data-start-date"));
  popover.find('.end-date-input').val( ymd(moment($(this).attr("data-end-date")).add(1,'days')));

  popover.find('.input-daterange .date-input').on('changeDate', function() {
  validateReservationDates($(this.form).find('.start-date-input'), $(this.form).find('.end-date-input'));
});
```

It recognizes the click but the popover is not shown. In fact, when clicked twice, the `console.log("asd");` is shown twice.

What am I missing?

Comment: you have `$(document).on('click', '.check-out-cell', function() {` twice in your code. You can combine both in one and write your code, does the same. I would like to see who calls popover() so that I can better understand your code and see what could be culprit.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit with that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I've managed to get this working, just needed to change the popover part with these little chunck:

```
var popOverSettings = {
  template: newPopoverTemplate,
  html: true,
  selector: '.check-out-cell',
  content: function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
  }
}
$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

The importante part is the selector field, which tells the popover what element to look for for its activation.